# Why is $\mathbb{Z}_m$ a commutative ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, relations, equivalence-relations, finite-rings

I understand for it to be a ring it has to be closed under the addition and product, have inverses for the additive group, distributive and identity in the product.

I can see that it is closed under addition and product, but I can't get the inverses in the additive group.

If $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is composed of equivalence classes ${\underline{0},\underline{1},\underline{2},...,\underline{m-1}}$, I think I have to find an equivalence class $\underline{y}$ for every class $\underline{x}$ such that $\underline{x} - \underline{y} = 0$. Am I right?

And how do I do that?

Comment: Additive inverse to $x$ is an element $y$ such that $x+y=0$. Given any $x$, then you know that $m-x$ is the right one

Comment: Quotient rings of commutative rings are commutative

Comment: First I suppose you mean $x\color{red}+y=0$.  That said, it's quite simple: for any $0\le k\le m-1$, one has $k+(m-k)=0$.

Comment: Terminology comment: in group theory the terms "abelian group" and "commutative group" are synonyms, with "abelian" being more frequent, but in ring theory the only term that is used is "commutative ring".  Nobody speaks of "abelian rings".

Comment: You are apparently asking why the cosets of an abelian group form an abelian group. You probably want to replace "ring" with "group" in your title, if that is all. "Abelian ring" also has a totally different meaning in some of the ring theory litearture.

Comment: @KCd Well, not *nobody*. The use of "abelian ring" to mean "all idempotents are central" is pretty well established.

Comment: Abelian ring means that the "product" monoid in the ring is abelian. Makes sense, I think.

Also, I don't know how to proof anything except for closure of addition and product, so I think the question is right - I want to know why $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is a commutative ring, because I also don't know how to proof the commutative part.

Comment: @rschwieb thanks for pointing that out, I did not know such usage for  noncommutative rings.  In any case, the OP didn't have that as the intended meaning of "abelian ring".

Answer (score 1):

Let us choose a specific example: $m = 10$. Then

- $1 + 9 = 0$ so $9 = -1$
- $2 + 8 = 0$ so $8 = -2$
- $3 + 7 = 0$ so $7 = -3$
- $4 + 6 = 0$ so $6 = -4$

and so on. This is because $10 = 0$ in $\mathbf{Z}_{10}$.

In general $x + (m - x) = m = 0$ in $\mathbf{Z}_m$.

---

You can also think of this as a clock. For example:

- 9 o'clock is 3 hours to midnight. Thus $9 = -3$.
- 11 o'clock is 1 hour to midnight. Thus $11 = -1$.

Comment: But that is just about numbers. We don't have equivalence class $\underline{m}$, so that doesn't work, I think.

Comment: @dumb_undergrad I'm working with equivalence classes, I just didn't want to write `\underline` 20 times.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks, I think that works for additive inverses. Gotta think about the other stuff now.